# Within a dice roll event listener, how can I delay an alert until after the new dice images have loaded?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm practicing javascript and have created a little dice roll thing with two dice, and numbers 1-12. The dice are rolled, the number (1-12) that matches the dice roll total gets a red dashed border, and when you click on it, it turns gray.

My image sources are "die_1" through "die_6" and I just randomly generate a number 1-6 and then plop it into the "die_" string to change the src of the image.

Now, if the number that you roll is ALREADY gray, I have an alert pop up that says "Roll again."

My question is: in my current implementation, the alert pops up before the images of the dice have changed. Once I click "OK" the dice change to show the number that rolled. Is there a way to delay the alert until the images of the dice have changed?

```
var diePicture1 = document.getElementById("die1");
var diePicture2 = document.getElementById("die2");
const NUMBERBUTTONS = document.querySelectorAll(".number-button");
buttonRoll = document.getElementById('roll');

/* Gets the values of the dice and adds them */

function totalDice(){
  var die1Value = parseInt(diePicture1.src.substring(diePicture1.src.length - 5,diePicture1.src.length-4));

  var die2Value = parseInt(diePicture2.src.substring(diePicture2.src.length - 5,diePicture1.src.length-4));

  var result = die1Value + die2Value;

  return result;

}

buttonRoll.addEventListener('click', function(){

/*Randomly generates two numbers 1-6
then changes the img src to match */


  var dieNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) +1;
  var dieNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) +1;
  diePicture1.src = "die_" + dieNumber1 +".png";
  diePicture2.src = "die_" + dieNumber2 +".png";
  var total = totalDice();

/*Checks to see if there are any numbers leftover
with a red border. If so, clears them */

  currentNumber = NUMBERBUTTONS[total-1];
  for (i=0; i<12; i++) {
    if (NUMBERBUTTONS[i].style.border = "2px dashed red"){
      NUMBERBUTTONS[i].style.border = "";
    }
  }

/*Gives red border if the color is not gray already */


  if (currentNumber.style.background != "gray") {
    currentNumber.style.border = "2px dashed red";
  } else {

/*this is what is popping up before the dice images have had a chance 
to change on screen */

    alert("Roll Again");
  }

}, false);

/*Turns number gray when clicked on IF border is red */
document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  if (e.target.style.border === "2px dashed red"){
    e.target.style.border = "";
    e.target.style.background = "gray";
  }


},false);
```

Comment: I believe `diePicture1` has a `onload` you can make usr of

Comment: Thanks. I could even move the entire rest of this to an event listener for "load" within the buttonRoll event listener.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quite easy.
The set time out function takes two argument, what you want to run and the timing you want for it to run so for this put your alert into the method and set time out.

Follow the link for more details
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried adding the setTimeOut method? Set time out for the alert to pop up to be after the images of the dices have changed.

Comment: Great idea. What's the proper syntax to applying this to only the alert function?

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

```
  var dieNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) +1;
  var dieNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) +1;
  diePicture1.src = "die_" + dieNumber1 +".png";
  diePicture2.src = "die_" + dieNumber2 +".png";
  var total = totalDice();

  var promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    diePicture1.addEventListener('load', () => {
      resolve();
    })
  })

  var promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    diePicture2.addEventListener('load', () => {
      resolve();
    })
  })
...

Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(() => {alert('Roll Again')})
```

Here, the alert won't occur until both images are loaded.